# Filter table to unique IDs without subquery

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I've got a table that looks something like this:

| User ID (`sorhsch_pidm`) | High school (`sorhsch_sbgi_code`) | Surrogate ID (`sorhsch_surrogate_id`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | blah HS | 1 |
| 123 | blah2 HS | 2 |
| 234 | blah HS | 3 |
| 345 | blah4 HS | 4 |
| 567 | homeschool | 5 |

Contextually, I'd expect this particular table's schema to enforce uniqueness on the `sorhsch_pidm` field. (according to my vendor, the `surrogate_id` field is just a row number.) The problem is that it *doesn't*. I'm not sure why, but what I know is that I need to reduce it down until no `sorhsch_pidm` has >1 row. I don't really care which row gets chosen, only that exactly one remains for later querying.

Of course, I can do something like:

```sql
select sorhsch.* --IE select arbitrary tables
from sorhsch
inner join (
    select sorhsch_pidm as pidm,
           max(sorhsch_surrogate_id) as good_row
    from sorhsch 
    group by sorhsch_pidm) sorhsch_filter
on sorhsch_pidm = pidm
and sorhsch_surrogate_id = good_row;
```

but this solution has me defining a subquery, which I personally dislike. Is there a way of solving this problem without using subqueries, CTEs, or views?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *row limiting clause with the `WITH TIES` option* as the following:

```
select * from sorhsch
order by row_number() over (partition by sorhsch_pidm order by sorhsch_surrogate_id desc)
fetch next 1 row with ties
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Ust8MDA)

Comment: ok so if I'm reading this right, the `order by` establishes the # of that ID we've seen, and then the `fetch` filters it to the first example. Do you have any additional documentation I can read to learn more about the behavior of `partition by` in the `order by` clause?

Comment: Looks like the Oracle blog has more info: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-select-the-top-n-rows-per-group-with-sql-in-oracle-database

Comment: The `row_number` function will number the returned rows starting from 1 for each `sorhsch_pidm` group according to the max `sorhsch_surrogate_id`, then the with ties option will ensure the selection of row number 1 for each group.

Comment: The with ties option is connected to the order by and limiting clause, meaning, the order by here will return rows with row_number = 1 first, then the `with ties` will return more rows with values that match the last row in the limited result set.